# Return the name with the maximum number of characters for each customer id. Working in Azure Synapse Analytics using SparkSQL

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I have a table that is returning multiple rows for the same ID because of the differences in the name column. Some names include middle initials after the first name or suffix after the last name. In the below example, I want only the first row because it has the complete name.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2345678999 | Johnson JR, Carl A |
| 2345678999 | Johnson, Carl |

I tried to rank by length of name but it returned
Error for undefined function LEN

```
with RANKEDROWS AS (
    select 
        ID
        ,NAME
        ,rank() over (order by LEN(name) DESC) AS ROWRANK
    FROM MEMBERS
)
select  ID, NAME
froM RANKEDROWS
WHERE ROWRANK = 1;
```

I tried to separate the names but it returned two rows - one with what is before the comma and one with what is after it instead of creating additional columns with the name parts.

```
select id, explode(split(NAME, ',')) as m_name
from members
```

Comment: What version of SparkSQL do you use? Try to use `LENGTH` rather than `LEN`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LENGTH` instead of `LEN`

[image]